# Creating dynamic html links for data retrieved from database

Tags: python, html, elasticsearch, flask

I am making a search engine using flask and html while using elasticsearch for search functionality.
This is my **app.py** file

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

app = Flask(__name__)
es = Elasticsearch()
@app.route('/',methods=["GET","POST"])
def index():
    q = request.form.get("q")
    if q is not None:
        resp = es.search(index='aman', body={"query": {"match":{"NAME": q}}})
        return render_template('index1.html', q=q, response=resp["hits"]["hits"])
    else:
        return render_template('index1.html')

if __name__ =="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This is my **index.html file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/" method="post" autocomplete="off">
        <label for="q"> search here : </label><input type="text" name="q" id="q" value="{{q}}">
        <input type="submit" value="search">
    {{response}}

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

My data is stored in json format. So, upon searching json formated data is retrieved. Since several docs can be retrieved at once depending on the query, it looks shabby on a single page. 
[Shabby representation of data obtained upon searching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LplEK.jpg)
So i tried making it cleaner by making html links and displaying just name of data using ordered list in html. I did this by replacing **{{response}}** from index.html with :

```
    <ol>
        {% for resp in response %}
        <li><a href="{{resp['_source'].url}}"> {{resp._source.NAME}}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ol>
```

Now i am getting data in desired format i.e. [result displayed in desired format.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w63Z5.jpg)
This issue with this is that ideally on clicking the url link i should get data associated with that url. But it doesn't return anything.

Comment: Does resp['_source'] have url attr? I can't see it in image?

Comment: @Srikanth No. It does not have url attribute. If i remove .url from the above mentioned code, I get the following error on clicking on the link. ``` The requested URL was not found on the server.```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The requested URL was not found on the server

This error is very obvious because you have only one route at `/`. You can solve this problem in two ways. You can either add route that adds the view for individual item or make your items collapsible in same page. I think it is better to add collapsible items so you don't have to hit elastic search again.

Sample code which shows cards with NAME and content as ABOUT. You can customize this however you want. More about collapse cards here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/collapse/.

```
<ol>
    <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
        <div class="card">
        {% for resp in response %}
            <div class="card-header" id="heading{{ loop.index }}">
                <h2 class="mb-{{ loop.index }}">
                    <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse{{ loop.index }}" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse {{ loop.index }}">
                        {{resp._source.NAME}}
                    </button>
                </h2>
            </div>

            <div id="collapse {{loop.index}}" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="heading{{loop.index}}" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                <div class="card-body">
                    {{resp._source.ABOUT}}
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
</ol>
```

Comment: This helped. Thank you sir!